# Is there a way to merge 2 arrays in GREL

Tags: openrefine

In a GREL expression, is there a way to merge 2 arrays?
I tried ["a","b"]+["c","d"] but the result is a java error.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Not with Grel.

Here is the complete list of the ["arrays" methods](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Array-Functions) in Grel and their [respective Java code](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/tree/master/main/src/com/google/refine/expr/functions/arrays). It should not be very difficult to add a "merge" or "append" method, but would it be worth it? It is very rare to have more than one array in a cell (I have never encountered this case).

It is precisely to solve this kind of rare but possible case that Open Refine offers two other more powerful scripting languages, Jython and Clojure. In Python/Jython, the operation you want to do is as simple as:

```
return [1,2,3] +[3,4,5] #result : [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Would it be possible/worth the effort to make it easier with some Grel new function?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it (though it might be a bad idea):

```
split(join(["a","b"], "|") + "|" + join(["c","d"], "|"), "|")
```

Join each array with a delimiter character that does not appear in the data. (I've chosen the pipe character.) Add the resulting joined-up arrays together, and add the delimiter between them. Now, they form the string `a|b|c|d`. This string can be split on the `|` delimiter into a new array.